# Facebook Comments Box test application

Tags: html, facebook, url, comments, localhost

I have been building a site using basically html coding and have come stuck across a little problem that im sure somebody may be able to help me with.

The facebook comments box dosent seem to appear when i am trying to add the text shortcut to a site that ive created stored on a localfile. For example the site is called: file:///F:/GoogleMaps_FusionTables/WorkingCheckBox.html due to it being developed within a html file editor and not yet placed on a website.Is there anyway of getting this to test here before uploading it to a website server?

Any assistance or advice you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Ian Usher

Comment: Try installing a webserver and test it locally??

Answer (score 0):

using a local web server will solve your problem.